# Python Find and Replace in JSON data

Tags: sql, python-3.x

API response contains apostrophe (') that is throwing off subsequent SQL code. How can I find and replace the character before sending the JSON object to SQL DB?

```
{
"num_results": 455161,
"results": [
    {
        "activity_date": "1975-12-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.",
        "operator_country_lar": "France",
        "operator_country_lar_id": "865",
        "operator_id": "2786"
    },
    {
        "activity_date": "1974-10-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.",
        "operator_country_lar": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
        "operator_country_lar_id": "206",
        "operator_id": "29080"
    }
],
"results_this_page": 2,
"status": 200}
```

I tried to convert JSON to str and then .replace(" ' ",""), but the data couldn't be returned to JSON.

```
convert_str = str(self.response.json())

convert_str = convert_str.replace("'","")

print(json.dumps(convert_str, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will successfully strip the unwanted apostrophe.

```
>>> d = {
     'num_results': 455161,
     'results': [{'activity_date': '1975-12-01',
                  'activity_id': '50',
                  'activity_name': 'ORDERED',
                  'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.',
                  'operator_country_lar': 'France',
                  'operator_country_lar_id': '865',
                  'operator_id': '2786'},
                 {'activity_date': '1974-10-01',
                  'activity_id': '50',
                  'activity_name': 'ORDERED',
                  'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.',
                  'operator_country_lar': "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
                  'operator_country_lar_id': '206',
                  'operator_id': '29080'}],
     'results_this_page': 2,
     'status': 200}
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(json.loads(json.dumps(d).replace("'", "")))
{'num_results': 455161,
 'results': [{'activity_date': '1975-12-01',
              'activity_id': '50',
              'activity_name': 'ORDERED',
              'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.',
              'operator_country_lar': 'France',
              'operator_country_lar_id': '865',
              'operator_id': '2786'},
             {'activity_date': '1974-10-01',
              'activity_id': '50',
              'activity_name': 'ORDERED',
              'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.',
              'operator_country_lar': 'Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of',
              'operator_country_lar_id': '206',
              'operator_id': '29080'}],
 'results_this_page': 2,
 'status': 200}
```

For `operator_country_lar` you could either use double quotes, "People's",
or escape with backwhack, 'People's'.

Rather than munging the whole JSON string,
you may find it helpful to visit each `dict` `key,val` item
and munge the individual `val` string.
For example:

```
for result in d['results']:
    for k, v in result.items():
        result[k] = v.replace("'", "")
```

> API response contains apostrophe (') that is throwing off subsequent SQL code.

This makes it sound like you've managed to launch a sql injection attack against yourself.
Recall the lesson of little [Bobby Tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).

It's important to use the proper database API for the proper purposes.
Rather than put quoted strings in a WHERE clause,
much better to pass them in as separate bind parameters
so the issue of quoting doesn't even come up.

Comment: That worked!  Tell me more on your second point regarding visiting each `dict` to escape each value.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar issues storing large JSON files as binary large objects in PostgreSQL DBs. I found using the ast literal_eval solution works well for serializing and de-serializing potentially volatile text:

```py
import json
from ast import literal_eval

s = ('''[
       {
        "activity_date": "1975-12-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.",
        "operator_country_lar": "France",
        "operator_country_lar_id": "865",
        "operator_id": "2786"
       },
       {
        "activity_date": "1974-10-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.",
        "operator_country_lar": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
        "operator_country_lar_id": "206",
        "operator_id": "29080"
       }
     ]''')

s = literal_eval(s)
d = json.dumps(s)
l = json.loads(d)

print(s)
print("")
print(d)
print("")
print(l)

"""

[{'activity_date': '1975-12-01', 'activity_id': '50', 'activity_name': 'ORDERED', 'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.', 'operator_country_lar': 'France', 'operator_country_lar_id': '865', 'operator_id': '2786'}, {'activity_date': '1974-10-01', 'activity_id': '50', 'activity_name': 'ORDERED', 'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.', 'operator_country_lar': "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", 'operator_country_lar_id': '206', 'operator_id': '29080'}]

[{"activity_date": "1975-12-01", "activity_id": "50", "activity_name": "ORDERED", "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.", "operator_country_lar": "France", "operator_country_lar_id": "865", "operator_id": "2786"}, {"activity_date": "1974-10-01", "activity_id": "50", "activity_name": "ORDERED", "activity_remark": "FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.", "operator_country_lar": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "operator_country_lar_id": "206", "operator_id": "29080"}]

[{'activity_date': '1975-12-01', 'activity_id': '50', 'activity_name': 'ORDERED', 'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.', 'operator_country_lar': 'France', 'operator_country_lar_id': '865', 'operator_id': '2786'}, {'activity_date': '1974-10-01', 'activity_id': '50', 'activity_name': 'ORDERED', 'activity_remark': 'FOR DELIVERY 1976-04.', 'operator_country_lar': "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", 'operator_country_lar_id': '206', 'operator_id': '29080'}]

"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Not sure its working for me though. I am getting error `in _convert_num raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))`

Comment: @AlenGiliana Snippet?